# What is $f(A)$ for $f(x)=x+(1/x)$ and $A=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:1/2<|x|<2\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

For $f:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $f(x)=x+(1/x)$ and $A=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:1/2<|x|<2\}$.

> What is $f(A)$?

I know that $f(A)$ is an ellipse of sorts, but I'm not sure how it looks exactly. I thought about filling in some circles in $f$, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: what happens for $|x| = 1$?

Comment: @amcalde then $f=2$

Comment: Not quite. That is only true for $x = 1$

Comment: @amcalde can I rewrite $f(x)$ to $f(|x|)$?

Comment: Note that $f(x)=f(1/x)$, so the image of $\vert z \vert = r$ will be the same as the image of $\vert z \vert = 1/r$. You can thus consider the image of $f$ on $1\le \vert z \vert < 2$, where $f$ is univalent (single-valued). [except on $\vert z \vert = 1$]

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform

Comment: @πr8 I'm not sure what you mean by univalent, and what happens for $|z|=1$?

Comment: @Spider-Pig Univalent = injective, in this context, i.e. it maps different points to different points. On $\vert z \vert=1$, it doesn't do this, but you can sidestep this problem by noting that the image of this set under $f$ is $[-2,2]$.

Comment: @πr8 Thanks, I get that now, but what does the image of $f$ look like on $1\leq |z|<2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(z)=f(1/z)$, so the image of $|z|=r$ will be the same as the image of $|z|=1/r$. You can thus consider the image of $f$ on $1≤|z|<2$ where $f$ is univalent (single-valued) [except on $|z|=1$, though this poses few actual problems].

So, we need only consider the action of $f$ on $\{1 \le\vert z \vert < 2\}$. We break this down by seeing how it acts on each circle $\vert z \vert = r$ and then reuniting them.

On $\vert z \vert = r$, $z=re^{i\theta}\implies f(z)=re^{i\theta}+\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}=\left(r+\frac{1}{r}\right)\cos\theta+i\left(r-\frac{1}{r}\right)\sin\theta$, which traces out the ellipse (viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$)

$$\frac{x^2}{\left(r+\frac{1}{r}\right)^2}+\frac{y^2}{\left(r-\frac{1}{r}\right)^2}=1$$

(note that this fails for $r=1$, though it can readily be seen that the image of the unit circle is $[-2,2]$ by writing $z=e^{i\theta}\implies f(z)=2\cos\theta$)

As $r$ increases from $1$ to $2$, $r+\frac{1}{r}$ increases from $2$ to $5/2$, and $r-\frac{1}{r}$ increases from $0$ to $3/2$. One can see visually that as $r$ increases, the images of the $r$-circle form an increasing sequence of concentric ellipses, and so their union is simply the largest of these ellipses (including its interior), i.e.

$$\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}\le1$$

or, viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$:

$$f(A)=\frac{(\Re z)^2}{\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{(\Im z)^2}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}\le1$$